# Should MVP model contain android specific term?

Tags: android, android-context, android-mvp

I can do the logical things inside MVP view, but as far as I know, according to MVP pattern, view should be as dumb as possible. Can MVP model contain android specific term? If not, then how can I use activity context inside MVP model?

Comment: Use a class that uses Activity context as an implementation detail.

Comment: Create a class, receive Context as constructor argument, expose a method that doesn't know about Context, then in your Presenter or whatever you receive your class instead of Context directly.

Comment: Can you spot me an use case where you want to achieve, i personally pass activitiy related values as constrcutor but not context.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath For something like : context.getSystemService() inside MVP model. For checking internet connection.

Comment: What i did was creating utils for network checking and used that before calling presenter methods, i think that usage won't break the rules of using MVP

Comment: That means you check network inside View/Presenter? Not in Model?

Comment: never use activity context outside activity/fragment/view instead you can use applicationContext

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the implementation of a Login feature based on the MVP pattern, where the model(LoginInteractor) will use the activity context.

So, we have to implement the following classes: `LoginActivity`, `LoginPresenterImpl` and a `LoginInteractorImpl` (as the MVP model). As MVP states, we will define a contract between the View and the Presenter. We name them `LoginView` and `LoginPresenter`. Additionally, we will also define an interface for the Interactor class, `LoginInteractor`.

The `LoginActivity` has a reference to the `LoginPresenter`, where all the logic will be handled. The concrete implementation, `LoginPresenterImpl` has reference to the `LoginView` and `LoginInteractor`. The concrete implementation for the interactor, `LoginInteractorImpl` will use the activity context to initialize Android specific resources that are necessary to gather the data required during the login process.

This way, the presenter logic remains agnostic regarding android resources and it can be easily unit tested.

Example code snippet (please observe, how the presenter knows only about an abstract Interactor. The concrete interactor is initialized in view, providing it's activity context.)

First, we define the contract for all the classes:

```
interface LoginView {

    fun onLoginSuccess()

    fun onLoginFailed()

    fun showErrorMessage(error: String)

    //...........
}

interface LoginPresenter {

    fun proceedLogin(username: String, password: String)

    //............
}

interface LoginInteractor {

    fun getUserByUsername(username: String) : User

    fun getUserCredentials() : Credential

    //............
}
```

Then, the concrete implementation for them:

```
class LoginActivity : LoginView, AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var presenter: LoginPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        // initialize presenter
        presenter = LoginPresenterImpl(
            view = this,
            interactor = LoginInteractorImpl(this)
        )

        // your code goes here
    }

    override fun onLoginSuccess() {
        // your code goes here
    }

    override fun onLoginFailed() {
        // your code goes here
    }

    override fun showErrorMessage(error: String) {
        // your code goes here
    }
}

class LoginPresenterImpl(
    private val view: LoginView,
    private val interactor: LoginInteractor
) : LoginPresenter {

    override fun proceedLogin(username: String, password: String) {
        // your custom login logic goes here
        // call interactor to get data
        // process data
        // give feedback to view
    }
}

class LoginInteractorImpl(context: Context) : LoginInteractor {

    override fun getUserCredentials() {
        // your code goes here
    }

    override fun getUserByUsername(username: String) {
        // use context to access local DB...
    }
}
```

Note: for better separation of concern, using a dependency injection solution would eliminate the problems arising from the fact that the View is initializing all the other objects.

Comment: I have 2 questions here - a) LoginInteractorImpl is MVP Model, and you used Context there. My confusion is here, doesn't that mean (Context) using android term inside model? b) You created a reference of LoginInteractorImpl inside MVP View (activity), isn't it creating a link between Model & View? I am new in MVP & not understanding these 2 points.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. For a better separation of concern a factory method should be used and dependency injection tools like [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/) or [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/). In some cases, it is inevitable to use context, especially when your datasource is some android specific resource. The way you wanna do it, is to hide the concrete implementation behind an abstract class/interface.

Comment: You are passing Context to interactor, thats not bad, as its not stored as property. But still in terms of unit testing it could be better to pass something more related to specific case. If you are using context for retrieving strings - then u could define LocalizationProvider or StringProvider and pass it inside interactor. It would be easier to mock in tests and yes kind of better layer separation.